# How can I read 16bit signed integers from my camera?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, real-time

I am using OpenCV to calculate the difference between to 8bit grayscal images. Neither cv::substract nor cv::absdiff do the job, sice I need to store the negative values as well. Therefore I tried converting both images to CV_16S, but it takes quite some time and reduces the speed of my realtime application. Is there a way to directly read the camera images as CV_16S? I tried

```
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_16S);
```

but the images from cap.read() still come as 8bit.

Comment: use the dtype parameter in cv::subtract: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20subtract(InputArray%20src1,%20InputArray%20src2,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20mask,%20int%20dtype)

Comment: Can you afford to reduce the images to 7-bit greyscale?  (0..127)  Then at least you know results in the range 129u..255u are actually negative.

Comment: Thank you both! I am trying to learn very sensible information from the images, therefore I decided to not use 7bit for the moment. dtype is exactly the option I was looking for, it is a little bit faster than before and much nicer.